# Is it possible to create a CMake-only project for Android Studio?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I have an 'MyLib.aar' project that creates my reusable module for multiple Android apps. My library links with some native C++ code in 'libMyNative.so', which is built with ndk-build.

I'd like to replace ndk-build with Android Studio CMake so as to build my native code with current standards.  The native code is built VERY rarely and I don't want to burden 'MyLib.aar' with those much longer build times, since it's built very frequently.

There appears to be little to no documentation describing this kind of build procedure.  The only thing covered in the official Android documentation states one should create a new Android Studio (app) project with C++ support and then bang on its 'CMakeLists.txt' file until it (as a by-product) generates what you want.

Ideally, my goal could be accomplished just with cmake if I knew how to hook into the Android Studio tool chain and pick up all the special environment variables it needs.

Is this possible?  And if so, how?

Comment: `ndk-build` is fully supported by Android Studio and not inferior to CMake. You don't need to switch.

Comment: If you mean that Android Studio new project wizard creates boilerplate for Android application, but not library — you can edit the build.gradle script for your library, following e.g. this simple example: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-libs/gen-libs/build.gradle. And in Android Studio you do *necessarily need to merge that project and the native build*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! CMake works the same in Android Studio as it would elsewhere. All the "special environment variables" are [right here in Android's docs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake)

so like the one thing you are going to want with a pure native app is

```
# build native_app_glue as a static lib
set(APP_GLUE_DIR ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue)
include_directories(${APP_GLUE_DIR})
add_library( app-glue STATIC ${APP_GLUE_DIR}/android_native_app_glue.c)
...
target_link_libraries(MyLibrary app-glue)
```

Other then that any other details you need are more CMake questions then NDK. Also note you can pass arguments in through Gradle

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
       abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
       arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang', '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static'
    }
}
```

---

**BETTER EDIT** - I realized the question was aimmed towards having a c++ library with  it loaded in at runtime from Java/Kotlin.

Here you want to make sure your app build.gradle has

```
externalNativeBuild {
     cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

In your cmake you still want

```
add_library( MyNative SHARED
${NATIVE_SRC}/myCode.cpp)
...
target_link_libraries(MyNative otherNativeLibraries)
```

Then you just load it in with Java (not sure for Kotlin)

```
System.loadLibrary("MyNative");
```

From here it is a matter of building JNI (again not sure for Kotlin) calls to plug into your libMyNative.so library, [LOT more detail about that here](https://github.com/sjfricke/Tango-C-NDK-Tutorial/blob/master/Section_01_NDK/Tutorials/Chapter_05.md)

Comment: Not sure I need 'native_app_glue', as I just want to build 'libMyNative.so' from C++ and it's just a library for use by Android apps -- be they native or Java or Kotlin.  I wrap that in a .aar but don't necessarily need to merge that project and the native build.  What would be the procedure for CMaking just the 'libMyNative.so'?

Comment: you should be able to build you library as normal in cmake with `add_library( MyNative ...` and `target_link_libraries(MyNative` and build it in gradle as an external build, then you can call
`System.loadLibrary("MyNative");` from your Java